# Add multiple text views programmatically in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

Here I have to add text view programmatically based on array list size. Text views should be appear in row like continues pattern...
eg. tv1, tv2, tv3 and so on till the size of array list.

But here I am getting text views which are appearing on each other. I can't read the text on them. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
if(languageNames.size()>0)
{
    int size = languageNames.size();
    TextView[] tv = new TextView[size];
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvLocation.getId());

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        tv[i].setText(languageNames.get(i).toString());
        tv[i].setLayoutParams(p);
        tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
        tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        rl.addView(tv[i]);
    }
}
else
{

}
```

what needs to be done so that I can get text views in appropriate manner?

Comment: You LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and set orientation as VERTICAL

Comment: set id for the TextViews.

Comment: p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvLocation.getId()); will make all the textviews stack below tvLocation.

Comment: @Tarun... I need all textviews below tvLocation..

Comment: User LinearLayout and set its orientation:Vertical it will set below textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add buttons inside a `LinearLayout` and add this `LinearLayout` in the `RelativeLayout`.

```
RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.r1);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvLocation.getId());
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

   for (int i=0;i< size;i++) {
     tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    tv[i].setText(languageNames.get(i).toString());

    tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
    tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
     LL.addView(tv);   
 }
r1.addview(LL, p);
```

Comment: @Tarun...thanks for your answer. Here I am getting data in vertical manner... I want them in series like in horizontal mode...

Comment: You can change `LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);` to `LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`

Comment: @Tarun...I am getting output but here text views' size are different than the default text views. how can I set them as default size?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    TextView[] tv = new TextView[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        tv[i].setText("TextView "+ i);

        tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
        tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        rl.addView(tv[i]);
    }
```

Hope this will help you